# Manage Nuget packages under File menu VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I’m working on NuGet (Library Package Manager) customization, there I have a requirement to place “Manage NuGet Packages…”  sub menu item under File menu in VS2010. I have identified that the changes needs to be done on vsct file (NugetTools.vsct) but I’m not sure how to add File Menu item and then place “Manage NuGet Packages…” under File menu?

let me know if you have any idea on this?

As of now “Manage NuGet Packages…”  is appearing under Project menu item and under References of the Project (when right click references under project).

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need to put it there? The user should be capable of adding it there themselves.

- Tools -> Customize
- Select the second tab (Commands)
- In the dropdown select "File"
- Click the Add Command button
- Browse to Tools
- Add the cmdidAddPackagesForSolution item to your menu
- Close out of the dialog, open your file menu, check that it is in there.

Comment: No change to Nuget.vsct required ?

Comment: Nope, visual studio menus are totally configurable.  BTW that command is in the tools menu under library package manager by default.

Comment: Thanks. But am not able to see Add command button in File option.Is it not available in Vs2008?

Comment: 2008 is different, you need to hit "rearrange commands" first.